# Text Alignment in CSS3 Triangle

Tags: css, text

I'm having trouble styling text within a div, which is in the shape of a triangle. All done with CSS.

The triangle is currently positioned absolutely as it needs to be for a larger project (I've removed the code from the larger project as it's irrelevant).

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/patrickbjohnson/UPeCf/4/)

See the code below:

HTML

```
<div>Here is a Triangle</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.125em;
    width: 100%;
}

div:nth-child(1) {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;  
    border-left:    126px solid transparent;
    border-right:   126px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:  126px solid #D30000;
}
```

Comment: since the `div` has zero width, there will be a line break between each pair of words.

Comment: @JanDvorak I'm playing around with the width and see exactly what you're talking about. The only issue now is that it won't exist as a triangle but as a trapezoid.

Answer (score 0):

since the `div` has zero width, there will be a line break between each pair of words.

A solution might be to create the shape with one element, and have the text in another one.

You need to realise the triangle is actually a very thick border of a 0x0 element located at the top vertex, and position accordingly.

Here I've positioned the text at the baseline of the triangle and made its width from one vertex of the base to the other. Feel free to play with the text element's size to avoid the text overflowing the triangle. I'm afraid, however, that you can't just let the text flow inside a triangular shape:

HTML:

```
<div class="triangle"><div class="text">Here is a Triangle</div></div>
```

CSS:

```
div { /*your original CSS*/ }
div.triangle { /* your original CSS for div:nth-child(1) */ }

div.text {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -126px; /* baseline */
    left: -126px;   /* left tip */
    right: -126px;  /* right tip */
    width: auto;    /* reset width:100% from div */
    height: auto;   /* just in case */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/honnza/UPeCf/8/